# "Unsupported get request" with Rfacebook only on particular n

Tags: r, rfacebook

I am encountering the following error with the correct token, etc.

```
 Error in callAPI(url = url, token = token, api = api) : 
Unsupported get request. Object with ID '540404695989874_1594827280547605' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
```

However, I only encounter the error on this specific public page when requesting data above a certain n. I have encountered this error on other public pages, whereas some public pages do not throw this error and I can collect all the posts.

Is there a specific problem with the public page's post that prevents the getPage? In this example, I encounter the error when n = >200, but not below.

I am searching with the following parameters:

```
AFD_page <- getPage("alternativefuerde", token=fb_oauth, n = 1000, since = '2016/09/01', reactions = TRUE, api = "v2.10")
25 posts 50 posts 75 posts 100 posts 125 posts 150 posts 175 posts 200 posts 225 posts 250 posts 275 posts 300 posts 325 posts 350 posts 375 posts 400 posts 425 posts 450 posts 475 posts 500 posts 525 posts 550 posts 575 posts 600 posts 625 posts 650 posts 675 posts 700 posts 725 posts 750 posts 775 posts 800 posts 825 posts 850 posts 875 posts 897 posts
```

Answer (score 1):

This post dosen't exist on Facebook. Maybe AfD fanpage has deleted this?

Comment: Could it be then that Rfacebook throws an error whenever the getPage function encounters a page where a post has been deleted? Seems like a bug.

Comment: I think this is error in Facebook. `getPage()` without `reactions` and `api` parametres worked fine. May be also error in Rfacebook (put an issue to author if you want).

This one post `AFD_page %>% filter(post_ID == "540404695989874_1594827280547605")` looks strange to me - try to search it on Facebook and look what it is.